# Asp.net - Session Time out (close confirm message)

Tags: asp.net

Implemented this for session time out which is working fine:

```
var sessionTimeoutWarning = "1";
var sessionTimeout = "2";
var timeOnPageLoad = new Date();
var sessionWarningTimer = null;
var redirectToWelcomePageTimer = null;
//For warning
var sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('SessionWarning()', parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000);
//To redirect to the welcome page
var redirectToWelcomePageTimer = setTimeout('RedirectToWelcomePage()', parseInt(sessionTimeout) * 60 * 1000);

//Session Warning
function SessionWarning() {
    var minutesForExpiry = (parseInt(sessionTimeout) - parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning));
    //var minutesForExpiry = "1";
    var message = "Your session will expire in another " + minutesForExpiry + " mins. Do you want to extend the session?";

    //Confirm the user if he wants to extend the session
    answer = confirm(message);

    //if yes, extend the session.
    if (answer) {

        //Clear the RedirectToWelcomePage method
        if (redirectToWelcomePageTimer != null) {
            clearTimeout(redirectToWelcomePageTimer);
        }

        var currentTime = new Date();
        var timeForExpiry = timeOnPageLoad.setMinutes(timeOnPageLoad.getMinutes() + parseInt(sessionTimeout));
        if (Date.parse(currentTime) > timeForExpiry) {
              alert("Session expired. You will be redirected to welcome page");
            window.location = "../login.aspx";
        }
        else {
            timeOnPageLoad = new Date();
            sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('SessionWarning()', parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000);
            redirectToWelcomePageTimer = setTimeout('RedirectToLoginPage()', parseInt(sessionTimeout) * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }
    else {
        timeOnPageLoad = new Date();
        sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('SessionWarning()', parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000);
        redirectToWelcomePageTimer = setTimeout('RedirectToLoginPage()', parseInt(sessionTimeout) * 1);

    }

}

//Session timeout
function RedirectToLoginPage() {
    window.location = "../login.aspx";
}
```

Query: when the confirm message comes up, how can we track/enable that if user didn't clicked in 5 mins on that confirmation message then I want to close that automtically and display new popup that session has expired.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control on the alert box once you have opened it. What most you can do is to refresh the page after 5 minutes of showing alert box. So you can write setTimeout after showing alert box and then redirect a page where you can display popup that session has expired.